# JPA, Hibernate, Embedded, and OneToOne

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm using JPA and Hibernate, and have an `@Entity` which includes an `@ElementCollection` of an `@Embeddable` component, which has two `@Embeddable` components itself, of the same type, which have a `@OneToOne` association with another `@Entity`.

Basically:

```
@Entity
public class Company {
    // ...
    @ElementCollection
    private List<Employee> employees;
    // ...
}

@Embeddable
public class Employee {
    // ...
    @Embedded
    private Address residentialAddress;
    @Embedded
    private Address postalAddress;
    // ...
}

@Embeddable
public class Address {
    // ...
    @OneToOne
    private HousingInfo housingInfo;
    // ...
}
```

(Note that the names of the classes have been changed to protect the innocent.)

Now, the problem I'm having is I'm getting an error trying to autoupdate the schema:

> create table company_employees (company_id bigint not null, employees_collection&&element_residential_address_housing_info tinyblob, employees_collection&&element_postal_address_housing_info tinyblob)

MySQL clearly doesn't like the `&&`s.  We're using a subclass of `org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy`, which doesn't insert `&&`s anywhere that I can see.

I tried `@AssociationOverride`, but it appeared to be ignored, regardless of which level I put it at.  That is, I tried overriding the attributes in `Company` (`@AssociationOverride(name = "residentialAddress.housingInfo', joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "residential_housing"))` on the `List`, etc.), and also tried it in `Employee` (`@AssociationOverride(name = "housingInfo", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "residential_housing"))` on `residentialAddress`, etc.), but neither seemed to do anything, at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `@AttributeOverride` worked, even though, from the documentation, it seemed I was supposed to use `@AssociationOverride`.